# When to send packets in multiplayer game loop?

Tags: c++, multiplayer

I'm programming my first multiplayer game loop and right now my loop consists of:

1. logic
2. process keyboard input
3. process mouse input
4. draw

At what point in the loop is it best to send packets to the server?

My current game loop:

```
    while (!key[KEY_ESC]) {
        while (speed_counter > 0) {
            update();
            keyboard();
            mouse();
            speed_counter--;
        }
        if(game_time - old_time >= 10) {
            fps = frames_done;
            frames_done = 0;
            old_time = game_time;
        }
        draw();
        frames_done++;
    }
```

Comment: Won't the code shown above stop processing mouse and keyboard information after the first iteration of the outer while loop?  It looks like speed_counter would decrease to zero and then remain zero forever after, and therefore the inner while loop would never again be entered.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm using a timer to increment speed_counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to send packets after input is received (in this case both keyboard and mouse) so that all moves can be updated at the same time. You would want a step 3.5 that was something like `update other players` if I understand your question correctly

Comment: I added my code to my question, where would I send the packets in the code?

Comment: The best time to send the packets would be as soon as you have the data ready that you want to include in them.   You can't send them sooner than that, because you wouldn't know what to send, and you wouldn't want to send them later then that, because the longer you hold on to the data before sending it, more time will pass before the other players can see the updated data.